# validate only on some method rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Based on rails validation [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on). I need to validate `fullname` field only on update

```
# encoding: utf-8
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  GENDER_MALE = true
  GENDER_FEMALE = false

  attr_accessor :password_confirm,
                :term,
                :year, :month, :day,
                :captcha

  validates :username, presence: {message: "Bạn phải nhập tài khoản"},
                      uniqueness: {message: 'Tài khoản đã tồn tại'}, :on => :update
  # validates :password, presence: {message: "Bạn phải nhập mật khẩu"},
  #                     confirmation: {message: 'Mật khẩu không chính xác'}
  # validates :password_confirmation, presence: {message: "Bạn phải nhập xác nhận mật khẩu"}
  # validates :fullname, presence: {message: "Bạn phải nhập họ tên"}
  # validates :email, presence: {message: "Bạn phải nhập email"},
  #                   uniqueness: {message: "Email đã tồn tại"}
  # validates :email, format: {with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i, message: "Email không đúng định dạng"},
  #                   unless: "email.blank?"
  # validates :term, acceptance: {message: "Bạn phải đồng ý điều khoản"}
  # # validates :gender, acceptance: {accept: [0,1], message: "Giới tính không hợp lệ"}
  # validate :_birthday_validator
  # validate :_captcha_validator
  #
  # before_save :_encrypt_password

  def signup
    self.birthday = "#{year.to_s}-#{month.to_s}-#{day.to_s}"
    self.save
  end

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr, option = {})
    "" || super
  end



  protected
    def _encrypt_password
      self.password = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(password)
    end

  private
    def _birthday_validator

      unless year.present? && month.present? && day.present?
        errors.add(:birthday, 'Bạn phải nhập ngày sinh')
      else
        errors.add(:birthday, 'Ngày sinh không hợp lệ') unless Date.valid_date?(year.to_i, month.to_i, day.to_i)
      end
    end

    def _captcha_validator
      if !(captcha.nil?)
        errors.add(:captcha, "Mã xác nhận không hợp lệ") if captcha == false
      end
    end
end
```

As understand, this validation rule only run when I call update method, but I have no idea why this rule run all the time
[image]
Can anyone tell me why or I missed somethings?

Ps: Can Rails validates only for user defined method, somethings like
`validates :username, presence: true, only: [:my_func]`

Comment: Post code, not screenshots of code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I updated the Model code above, please help me

Comment: I found the answer myself. The code above pass the validation rule because when I call `update`, the user object is not exist in database, it's a new record, but `on: :update` just work only for an object that existed in database. <~ Right?

Comment: `on: :update` hooks are invoked only when updating existing records, yes.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to set a [virtual attribute](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes) which you'll only populate in the `signup` method:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :should_validate
   validates :fullname, presence: true, on: :update, if: "should_validate.present?" 
end
```

This way, you can then assign a value to `should_validate` only when you use `signup`:

```
def signup
   self.birthday = "#{year.to_s}-#{month.to_s}-#{day.to_s}"
   self.should_validate = true
   self.save
end
```

Comment: awesome logic...may be useful for user :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use method like

```
validate :fullname , on: :update

def fullname
   if self.fullname.present?
      true
   else
      false
   end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but maybe my question was not clear. I  would like to know how can I run a validation for only user define method. Ex: I define a method `signup`, in this method I call `self.save` to save to database, but I want the validate rule only rune when I call `@user.signup`

Comment: validate :fullname , , :if => lambda { self.exists? }

Comment: validate :fullname, :if => { controller.action_name == "signup"}

Comment: `controller.action_name == 'signup'` is not work for me, I get an error `undefined local variable or method controller`